# Unable to initialize boost::multi_array<T, n> unless T has a no-argument constructor

Tags: boost, copy-constructor, boost-multi-array

It seems that `boost::multi_array<T, n>` requires that `T` have a no-argument constructor.  Consider the following example.

```
#include <boost/multi_array.hpp>

class ConstructorHasArguments {
    ConstructorHasArguments(int arg) {};
}

int main() {
    boost::multi_array<ConstructorHasArguments, 1> foo;
    return 0;
}
```

This results in a compile error.

```
no matching function for call to ‘ConstructorHasArguments::ConstructorHasArguments()
```

The problem is that, when the copy constructor for `boost::multi_array<T,n>` tries to allocate space for the copy, it attempts to call `T()`.  I could, of course, add a no-argument constructor to my class.  But what if I have a class for which a no-argument constructor doesn't make sense?

**Is there a simple way to use boost::multi_array when T does not have a no-argument constructor?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not only the copy constructor - actually all constructors of `boost::multiarray` will call `allocate_space()`, which in turns invokes `std::uninitialize_fill_n(base, allocated_elements_, T());`. Therefore a constructor without argument is required here. I don't think there is a way to bypass it if you still want to use `boost::multi_array`. (I am referring to the source code of `boost-1.46.0`.)

An alternative may be like this: you allocate and initialize space by yourself. Then pass the address to `boost::multi_array_ref`. In this case you will have to manage the memory.

Comment: Thanks Danqi.  Indeed, it looks like `multi_array_ref` may be my best bet for now.  After some more digging, I found that there is a [bug report](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/6889) on this topic.

Comment: The proposed changes in the link are good. It really makes sense to separate memory allocation and initialization to different methods.